# How to use laptop as a display screen for Raspberry Pi3?

Tags: pi-3

I have Raspberry Pi 3 model B and I want to use my laptop as display screen but I don't have any HDMI cable but I do have an Ethernet cable. How can I use it to connect my laptop to Pi? I use my college Wi-fi.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a serial console with an `USB to Serial TTL converter`. Costs about 10 EUR. This has the advantage that it works even without network connection.

With network running on the raspi you can use `ssh` to connect. For both solutions there are many suggestions here. Google and/or search for it.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that you want to "see" the RPi graphical screen on your laptop.  Consider setting up a [Virtual Network Console (VNC)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md). A VNC server on the RPi and a VNC client on the laptop.

(If all you want is the console (text only) then the simpler SSH approach mentioned by Ingo should work.)

Comment: To speed you on your way - it should be mentioned that SSH is normally turned off for security in RPi distributions.  So it may be difficult to setup a headless RPi.  To get around this, place an empty file called "ssh" with no extensions into the boot partition of the SDCard.